# Hovering over transparent SVGs

Tags: css, html, svg

How do I get hover to work robustly with transparent SVG polygons?

In the code below, you'll see that the second triangle isn't readily recognizing `:hover` (and it fails completely when `stroke` attribute is deleted or `none`'d). In the third triangle, hover starts to work with transparency, but only near the text.

```
<html><head><style>
body { background-color: Green }
polygon:hover {
    fill:Red;
}
g:hover polygon {
    fill:Red;
}
</style></head><body>
    <svg width="300px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 100 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <polygon fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5px" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,0" />
        <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5px" points="0,0 0,100 100,100 0,0" />
        <g>
            <polygon fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5px" points="0,100 100,100 100,200 0,100" />
            <text x="50" y="150" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30">hi</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body></html>
```

I've confirmed this over Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  Any ideas (that'll work across most browsers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element state the fill color as `fill="red"`, and set 0 as the fill opacity `fill-opacity="0"`. On hover change the fill-opacity to 1:

```css
body {
  background-color: Green
}
polygon:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}
g:hover polygon {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 100 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <polygon fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5px" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,0" />
  <polygon fill="red" fill-opacity="0" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5px" points="0,0 0,100 100,100 0,0" />
  <g>
    <polygon fill="red" fill-opacity="0" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5px" points="0,100 100,100 100,200 0,100" />
    <text x="50" y="150" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30">hi</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  The easy fix shows me that I just asked an RTFM question.  What's your favorite resource for researching W3 SVG elements and finding the attributes that does what you figure?

Comment: I'm not sure it's really an RTFM. I had the same problem, and it took me awhile to find the simple solution, but maybe I haven't read the manual as well :) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG) is the all purpose web technologies resource. [Sara Soueidan[(https://sarasoueidan.com/articles/) also have some nice articles.

Comment: this is what pointer-events is for. Please don't use fill-opacity for this. 
Opacity costs resources and slows down your page and drains the battery of your consumers. 
Plus, sometimes you don't have full control of the markup. Using pointer-events is pure CSS and the recommended way to do this.

Comment: That's good to know. As I've said - **maybe I haven't read the manual as well** :) @enfascination - change the accepted answer to Holger's, so I can delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `pointer-events="all"`.

With pointer-events you can control wich part of your shape reacts to pointer-events, independently of its fill or stroke.

```css
circle:nth-of-type(1) {
  pointer-events: fill
}
circle:nth-of-type(2) {
  pointer-events: all
}
circle:nth-of-type(3) {
  pointer-events: stroke
}
circle:nth-of-type(4) {
  pointer-events: none
}
circle:hover {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue
}
```

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" />
  <circle cx="75" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="5" />
  <circle cx="25" cy="75" r="20" fill="green" stroke="none" stroke-width="5" />
  <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="20" fill="green" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
```